# Opacity as a background and images

Tags: css, html, z-index, opacity

Usually I can solve these, but I can't find a solution anywhere. I have a div with a set width and height and opacity of 0.8 that sits at the very top. I also have a banner that goes full screen, left to right.

The div is always in front of the banner, no matter what I do (floats, code rearrange, z-index), it makes no difference.

#### HTML

```
<div class="banner">
<img class="banner_image" style="z-index:100" src="/top_banner2.png" alt="banner" />

</div> <!-- end of banner -->


<div class="left" style="z-index:-100">


<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li class="left_words"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="left_words"><a href="/awesome.php">Awesome</a></li>
<li class="left_words">Catering</li>
<li class="left_words">Our Coffee</li>
<li class="left_words">Flow Chart</li>
<li class="left_words">Prototype</li>
<li class="left_words">Catering</li>


<ul/>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.banner{

    width: auto;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    z-index: 100;

}


.banner_image{
    margin-top: -20px;
        display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}


.left{


    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 800px;

    margin-left: 90px;

    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: .9;
    padding-top: 250px;
    margin-top: -200px;
z-index: -100;
}

.left_words{

    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.banner`. I've included the entire working solution in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkppT/) (color-coded for clarity).

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you very much, I appreciate it. This is a great community.